# finite group actions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective and separated $k$-scheme and $G$ a finite group acting on $X$. Suppose $\mathrm{char}(k)$ does not divide the group order. Then there is the quotient stack $[X/G]$. In this a quasi-compact, separated DM-stack whose coarse moduli space is a scheme?

Comment: Since $X$ is quasi-projective, isn't $X/G$ already a scheme?

Comment: You are right. It is again a quasi-projective scheme but maybe singular.